# How do I create a conditional-type JOIN or WHERE clause when the condition is "missing data"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements

I'm currently trying to use my business's accounting data to back-build a comprehensive commissions table.

Each company that does business with us gets a unique ID number. Since we have more than one division of business, the company could conceivably have a dedicated salesman for Division-A and a different one for Division-B.

Because paperwork sometimes gets confused, one of the managers wanted me to go back to the Customer ID/Division level to build a table that assigned all instances of sales to the correct salesman by the customer ID/division pairing (i.e., Customer 12345678/Division A sales go to Employee 235 and 12345678/Division B sales go to Employee 777).

My initial query works by finding all the General Ledger documents that hit the GL accounts relevant to this manager's side of the business (defined in the CTE that picks up all the document numbers - called CT), and then tracking down the associated invoice (GL 12050) to find the customer number and division the invoice was charged to. However, I just learned that there are certain GL accounts that never get a 12050-invoice assigned to them.

Here's how the CTE (alias CT) "picks up" records I want to locate:

```
;WITH CT AS (
SELECT [GLAccount]
      ,[DocNumber]
      ,SUM([Amount]) AS [Amount]
      ,[WorkOrderNumber]
      ,[Salesman]
  FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[vCODADocDetails]
 WHERE (
        [GLAccount] IN ('42503','42504','42500','43625','43620','43621','43640','52503','52504','52500','53625','53620','53640',
                        '42530','42540','52530','52540','63100','62251',
                        '43601','43610','43615','43620','43621','43625','43627','43629','43630','43631','43635','43637','43640',
                        '43650','43660','43670',
                        '53601','53610','53615','53620','53621','53625','53627','53629','53630','53631','53635','53637','53640',
                        '53650','53660','53670',
                        '42500','42501','42503','42504','42505','42506','42508','42510','42511','42515','42520','42526','42530',
                        '42531','42533','42534','42535','42536','42540','42550','42560','42561','42565','42570','42580','42590',
                        '42630','42502',
                        '52500','52501','52503','52504','52505','52506','52508','52510','52511','52515','52520','52526','52530',
                        '52531','52533','52534','52535','52536','52540','52550','52560','52561','52565','52570','52580','52590',
                        '52630','52502',
                        '63310','63190','63230','63233','63290','63300','63900',
                        '62065','62120','62150','62190','62240','62250','62551','62900') 
            )
 GROUP BY [GLAccount], [DocNumber], [WorkOrderNumber], [Salesman]
```

This is my initial query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT DD.[DocNumber]
          ,CAST(DD.[Doc_Date] AS DATE) AS [DocDate]
          ,DD.[CustomerNumber]
          ,CT.[Division]
          ,CT.[GLAccount]
      FROM [DataWarehouse].[dbo].[vCODADocDetails] DD
     INNER JOIN CT
        ON DD.[FullDocNumber] = CT.[FullDocNumber]
     WHERE DD.[CustomerNumber] IS NOT NULL
       AND DD.[GLAccount] = '12050'
       AND DD.[Doc_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

But for the ones where there is no GL-12050 invoice assigned to them, I don't know how to make a join that only picks those up. Do I UNION some kind of other query to this one? Is there some kind of conditional JOIN I can do?

**EDIT:** Since someone asked for sample data and expected results, I thought I would add those.

**Example:** GL Account 43210 is not an account that gets associated with an invoice, but it *is* one that is tracked for commisisons purposes. So, the CTE might pick up something that looks like this:

```
GLAccount  DocNumber     Amount     WorkOrderNumber  Salesman
    43210  PIRF00428963  4151.78            RF65536       777
    13060  PIRF00428693  (1125.90)          RF65536
    13170  PIRF00428693  (3025.88)          RF65536
```

... where "43210" is one of the accounts I want to track the amount for. As you can see, there's no GL-12050 invoice assigned, because it doesn't track to that account. So, my "initial query" above won't find anything. What I would *like* it to return is the first line of my sample data, perhaps with some indication that it couldn't be matched to a 12050 record.

Comment: some sample data and expected result would be helpfull here

Comment: sidenote: beware of using `between`, read [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: Define what "picks those up" means. And what is CT? Did you accidentally drop the table name and leave just the alias? If it is a table name, then BE CONSISTENT! Best practice is to schema qualify object names, give them good aliases, and then use the appropriate alias when referencing columns.

Comment: And for future reference - Using the term "invoice" when your query does not reference a table / view with a name that includes that term is not very helpful. Not certain how you jump from "invoice" to "GLAccount" either. No one knows your schema, your jargon, and what your schema actually models.

Comment: Very messy description, but (from as much as I can understand) I would suggest using left join from CT to GL - this way you see all CT records and correspondigng data fom GL (if it exists). You should use GL limiting clauses directly on join condition, otherwise left join turns to inner one implicitly and you lose some records again. Or vice versa - your CT and GL relations are hard to see.

Comment: @Arvo got me headed in the right direction. Thank you!